# Google Sheets: How do I execute a formula in a column based on the value of a dropdown in another column?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

**Context**: I have an allocation Google Sheet.

1. Row 2 columns H to N:
2. I only want to sum the totals in row 2 columns H to N with/from the data in rows 3-5 columns H-N **if** Column E for any specific row is "High" or "Very High"
3. So a specific example - J2 would be 0.5 if E5's dropdown was "low"
4. Or, J2 would be 1.0 if E4 and E5 were "high" or "very high"
   [image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what does H-9 means?

Comment: @mike-steelson: My apologies, I corrected 9 was a typo for n, I was thinking niner when I went to type...too many years flying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in H2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(H3:H5*($E3:$E5="High")+H3:H5*($E3:$E5="Very High"))
```

drag to the right

Comment: I'm a reasonably intelligent dude - but I have to say, I'd be about 100 years old before figuring that out. Many thanks, @mike-steelson!!!!!